# Jquery Cookies expiration Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm using this code to show two different DIV using jquery cookies.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function showevent() {
      $(window).load(function() {
      if ($.cookie('MYCOOKIEVALUE') != '1'){

      setTimeout(function(){
      $('#event').fadeIn(); 
      jQuery.cookie('MYCOOKIEVALUE', '1', { expires: 31}); 
      }, 1000);}


      if ($.cookie('MYCOOKIEVALUE') == '1'){
      $('#event2').fadeIn();    
      }
});
});
</script>
```

I just need to modify the expiration time to 10 minutes using the exact code above.
Still very new in javascript and jquery ;(
Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do such specific timing you will need to use Javascript's built in Date object, like so:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (10 * 60 * 1000));
```

This works in milliseconds, so 1000 seconds x 60 seconds per minute x 10 minutes total, then change the line in your script above to use the new expiration date:

```
jQuery.cookie('MYCOOKIEVALUE', '1', { expires: date});
```

Comment: Just a quick question, What if I want to make the time like 90 minutes?. will it be like this?. 90 * 60 * 1000  ?

Comment: Yes, excatly like that!